# Spinner differently rendered in Gingerbread and Ice Cream Sandwich

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, android-4.2-jelly-bean

I don't understand why some elements are differently rendered. Here is a *emulated* ActionBar where I put a Spinner for changing the online status. However the text in the Spinner is visible on the Desire HD (2.3.5) and on the Nexus 7 (4.2.2), but on the LG P990 (4.0.4) the current spinner item is not visible I made the actual position with a green rectangle.

[image: GB and ICS screenshot]

Here is my code where I manipulate the Spinner a little so that the text is readable:

```
IcsSpinner status = (IcsSpinner)content.findViewById(R.id.status);
OnlineAdapter adapter = new OnlineAdapter(status.getContext());
status.setAdapter(adapter);
status.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
    public void onItemSelected(IcsAdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
        TextView tv = (TextView)parent.getChildAt(0);
        tv.setTextSize(12);
        tv.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
    }

    public void onNothingSelected(IcsAdapterView<?> parent) {
    }
});
```

By the way the default Spinner looks the same in the snippet above I'm using the back port from ActionBarSherlock.

I tried to use:

```
tv.setPadding(0, -12, 0, 0);
```

Which looks fine for the ICS device but on the GB and the JB it looks not so good.

What is the reason for this?
How can I detect if I need to correct the position?

Comment: i am also having same problem. Did you get a solution for this ??

Comment: No not yet, I can just guess that is somehow units dependend...

Comment: @kaluwila I think I found a reason it is something about the user defined font size (Settings -> Display -> Font Size).

Comment: ok rekire what should i do with the font size?

Comment: @kaluwila try using sp instad of dp. By code you can use  `TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 123f, res.getDisplayMetrics());`

Comment: i am using sp for all the font sizes but the issue is still there..:(

Comment: I think you need to use it also for all paddings and margins in sp